# how do I resolve module_init function definition file not found on terminal start up?

Tags: terminal, startup

When I start Terminal this is what comes up

```
Last login: Sat Jan 22 13:29:23 on ttys000
Users/finngraf/.zshrc:17: module_init: function definition file not found
finngraf@finns-macbook-pro ~ %
```

A friend showed me how to view the code that's trying to be run
by using `nano .zshrc` and going to line 17 because that's where the error is

So I run it and get this

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/finngraf/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)" if [
$? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup" else
    if [ -f "/Users/finngraf/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/finngraf/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/finngraf/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi fi unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

module_init
```

as far as I understand the issue is that it can't run this module_init command. I've tried to find out more about it, but I've hit a wall. Can anyone tell me how to resolve the error and maybe tell me what the cause of this issue might be?

I'm running MacOs 12.1 Monterey on A 2020 Mac Pro M1

Comment: The ~/.zshrc file is one you control and you make decisions as to what goes in there. You have allowed cond to setitself up in there. You have also either edited the file to add module_init or installed some other software that added that line. If you don't know what installed it then delete the line. Basically you should understand what each line in ~/.zshrc does or at least trust the program that added it - if not then delete it